# UI Issue on triage - Info modal is overlapping the flag modal

Tags: bug, triage

UI Issue on triage - Info modal is overlapping the flag modal

[image]

Also it overlaps question:

[image]

Comment: _“Also it overlaps question”_ — that is not a bug. This is a sticky header; that’s by design.

Comment: bit weird though. I would like to see the question rather than the header

Comment: Press "less" on the sticky header :)

Comment: there is no "less"

Comment: @AJ Yes, there is a link labeled “(less)”.

Comment: There's no "less" on the *second* dialogue. There is on the first.

Comment: yeah.. I was talking about 2nd :)